# how to write condition in prefix.pch

Tags: ios, objective-c, precompiled-headers

From prefix.pch I want to return 4 if iPhone is iPhone 4 or lower and 5 if iPhone is iPhone 5 or more...

I know how to know the height

```
#define iPhoneHeight [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
```

Based on this, I get height, but I want to return 4 or 5.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Please avoid to create a completely new tag like [prefix.pch], unless it is really necessary. I have replaced it by the exising tag [precompiled-headers].

Comment: It's a terrible idea to put this as a macro in a precompiled header.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper : Where? I don't know where to write macro

Comment: Not a macro at all. Perhaps, a category of `UIDevice` if the existing methods in `UIDevice` are not appropriate or not precise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare height with value in points for 4 inch display like this:

```
#define iPhone4Or5 [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568 ? 5 : 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this help ?

```
    #define isIPhone4or5 CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136)) ? 5 : 4
```

Comment: no.. I need in reply as 4 or 5 as I am setting images programmatically... so I will have is `mainBackground.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_Categories_iPhone%d.png", iPhone4Or5]];`

Comment: Then its easy it will be like this
#define isIPhone4or5 CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136)) ? 5 : 4